# Python 3 - Can't access variable inside function despite global keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, global-variables

In this stretch of code I can't access the `_frame_index` variable inside the update function.

I can access another variable defined outside the scope, why can't I access this one? I've tried with and without the global keyword, and outside the `if` scope.

```
_max_value = max(something)
_min_value = min(something)
_frame_index = 0

def update(_current_frame):
    #Ok!
    axes.set_zlim3d([_min_value, _max_value])

    if bool_test:
        global _frame_index
        # Raises - NameError: name '_frame_index' is not defined
        _temp = _frame_index
        _frame_index += 1

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames_vector)
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two variable calls? Why can one be seen from the inside scope but not the other?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `_frame_index` should be available, even if the `global` removed (all globals are locally available). You probably want to show a [mcve] of the issue, since the problem does not seem to occur in the part you show here. Also a clear problem statement would be helpful; i.e. what happens ("Not ok" is pretty unspecific)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed the line that raises the problem.
The error raised is `NameError: name '_frame_index' is not defined`
And the line that causes it is `_frame_index += 1`.
I will edit the original post.

Comment: In this case `global` is required indeed. But the code should work. Without [mcve] (i.e. a runnable code) one cannot help further here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to able to create a small example that replicates the error. If I solve it I'll post the answer, but for now any suggestions are highly appreciated!